# Route requests from subdomain to ports with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a domain (say `example.net`) with an Apache instance running on port 443. On the same host as `example.com` I have a web application running on port 9000, so I can access it if I go to `https://example.net:9000` in my browser.

What I want is to add some entry to my Apache config such that I can access the application running on port 9000 through a nicer link, such as `http://example.net/my-app`.

I have tried

```
<Location /my-app/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9000/
</Location>
```

and I can indeed retrieve the index of the `my-app` app but it messes up all of the Javascript and CSS references on the page.

I want something that will exactly mimic what happens when I go to `example.net:9000`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new `VirtualHost` to assign the `DocumentRoot` to the directory where your app is?

Comment: Nope, but I guess that's the next thing to try then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Alias**.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.net
    DocumentRoot /path/here

    Alias /my-app /path/to/myapp
    <Directory /path/to/myapp>
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The above setup would return the files from */path/here* if you go to **http://example.net** and would return files from **/path/to/myapp** if you go to **http://example.net/my-app**.